# Laplace transform of $H(-t)$

Tags: complex-analysis

How can I compute the Laplace transform of $H(-t)$, where $H$ is the Heaviside step function? Does it exist? Basically, I want to compute the Laplace transform of $e^{2t}H(-t)$. I know how to compute $e^{2t}H(t)$ but I have problem with the $H(-t)$.

Comment: Sure, it exists. What's your definition of the theta function and the transform?

Comment: My definition for the Heviside is: it equals 1 for t>0 and 0, for t<0. Its LT is 1/s, to tell you the truth I don't know what this means. Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Laplace transform of $f(t)$ where $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ does not care all about the values of $f(t)$ for $t < 0$. That is one of the reasons that the Heavyside function comes up so much in Laplace transform work, as $\mathcal L[f(t)] = \mathcal L[H(t)f(t)]$.

The Laplace transform of $H(t)$ is the same as the Laplace transform of the identity function

$$\mathcal L[H(t)](s) = \int_0^\infty H(t)  e^{-st} \ dt = \int_0^\infty 1 \cdot e^{-st} \ dt = \frac{1}{s} \ , \ s > 0$$

The Laplace transform of $H(-t)$ is the same as the Laplce transform of the zero function: zero.

$$\int_0^\infty H(-t)e^{-st} \ dt = \int_0^\infty 0 \cdot e^{-st} \ dt = \int_0^\infty 0 \ dt = 0$$

Given all that, what must the Laplace transform of $e^{2t}H(-t)$ be?

> $$\mathcal L[e^{2t}H(-t)](s) = \int_0^\infty e^{2t}H(-t) \cdot  e^{-st} \ dt = \int_0^\infty 0 \cdot e^{-st} \ dt = 0$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was very helpful.